# How to have different divs on different positions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am going to the following positions for my divs:

1. If I have two divs, they should be located in the middle of the page
2. If I have three divs, they should be located in one row
3. If I have four divs,  three of them should be in one row and the last one should be in the next row in the left
4. If I have five divs, three of them should be in one row and  the two last ones should be in the next row in the middle

My problem is the when I have four divs, the last one is in the middle of the next row.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="cards-overview" class="mt60"> 
    <div class="row-fluid" >
        <div class="span12">
            <div th:each="card, cardStat : ${dashboard.cards}"
                class="card-container-outer" style="display:      inline-block; text-align:left">
                <div class="card-container pointer">
                    <div th:switch="${card.status}">
                        <i th:id="${'card-status-' + card.windPowerStationId}"
                            th:case="1"
                            class="icon-status icon-status-ok card-status-tooltip navy-tooltip">
                            <span
                            th:id="${'card-status-description-' + card.windPowerStationId}"
                            th:text="${card.statusDescription}"></span>
                        </i> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mt60 {
margin-top: 60px;
text-align: center;
}

.card-container-outer {
width: 480px;
}

.card-container {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 310px;
height: 510px;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: instead of fixed pixels you need to work with percentages ie. a grid system. then your problem will solve itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work with percentages either. I set the width to 26% and get the same result when I have 4 divs.

Comment: have you tried this http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/animating-css-transitions.html

Answer (score 0):

(Tip : margin: 0 auto; is better than margin-left and margin-right auto)

You can center the first line and align left the last by putting this on the container :

```
text-align: center;
text-align-last: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly make these containers a little more malleable with `display:inline-block` with the full container being `text-align:center` - they will build on one another this way. Then if you write a small amount of jQuery to check for how many "containers" there are to assign the last element its alignment property.

```
var number = $('#containers').length();
if(number===4){
  $('#containers').last().css(//change the css properties to make the last div float left)
}
```

You could put a number of different `if/else` parameters in there to determine what the alignment should be.